# Speed in mph of vehicle spun in crash

Tags: geometry, circles

I witnessed a multi-vehicle crash last night, and was just reviewing my dash cam video. (You can see it [mp4 video, you'll have to download to view] at https://app.box.com/s/9f21n705od726fxjj1zbi8djiyvu92yo if you'd like).

The "middle" vehicle, a small pickup, was spun after being pushed by a vehicle passing him on the right. He hit a third vehicle 90 degrees through that spin. It took 25 frames (5/6 of a second) to spin another 270 degrees after the second impact. (Side note: the video above only shows about 10 frames a second, I'm counting off the original video at 30 fps)

For the sake of coming up with a best-guess value, I'm going to offer these assumptions:

- his speed at initial impact was 40 miles an hour
- at the point of second impact, he was moving at 5 miles per hour at a 90-degree axis to his original travel. The original spin had stopped and he was moving in a straight line.
- distance from the point of impact to the center of his mass was 10 feet
- (if it makes any difference, the truck he hit was moving 40 miles an hour at 90 degrees to the small truck's motion)

I have two questions:

- what was the linear speed of the driver, in mph, during the 5/6 of a second he spun 270 degrees?
- what force (pounds, units of gravity, whatever) did he undergo at impact (I'm thinking this is an instantaneous acceleration question)?

I understand the basics of the first calculation involve the radius (10 feet) and the radians he moved around the center point. But that's the limit of my understanding of this particular geometry problem. I have no clue how to calculate that instantaneous force.

The small truck driver was pretty dazed and was taken to the hospital. What I'm basically wondering is how badly his brain was shaken in his skull (coup-contracoup injury). I realize that's beyond the scope of this group, but with the two numbers calculated above, I can do some research on the head injury piece. It's all for interest sake, anyway...I don't know the guy.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Physics.SE]. PS why are you riding on the left lane forcing vehicles to pass you on the right? Also the truck on your right never pressed the brake, so he wasn't paying attention either (like the van that caused everyting).

Comment: I was driving at the speed limit, so generally that would mean a person would need to speed to pass me on the right. I had slowed below the speed limit for the left-turning truck seen at the start of the sequence. Hanging out in the left lane is a habit I got into when I worked EMS (avoids confusion when you light up while driving, keeping you from getting boxed in by people trying to get out of your way).   It hasn't gone away in the years since. If I don't see any answers here in the next day or so I'll close this and post on Physics. Thank you!

Comment: We were also a couple blocks past a commercial area where left turns are protected by islands and turning traffic in the right lane is frequent, so the lane I was in is the smoothest-flowing lane. My answer above is the primary reason, though...

Comment: Thanks for the video. I am going to show it to my kids so they understand the severity of a crash at 40mph and all the factors that played a role.

Comment: Was the turn signals on for truck turning left in front of the van? It seems the van was veering & the truck didn't use a turn signal to alert the van he was slowing down.

Comment: I'm not sure. Based on the behavior of the van driver after the accident, I'm not completely certain the pickup was turning -- she was saying "I'm sorry, I'm so sorry" -- just beside herself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question really needs to be posted to [Physics.SE]

There are two components of acceleration (and forces) at play. One is the deceleration of the center of mass and the second is the spin and the centrifugal forces.

My estimation is that the front of the red truck came to a stop really fast (the truck center of mass remains near the impact location along the road). You can see the bed cover flying out at about the speed the truck had before impact. I also estimate about 40mph before impact and 0mph after impact. I think happened over 0.2 seconds, so the decelleration is

$$ a = \frac{40 {\rm mph}}{0.2 {\rm sec}} = 89.6 {\rm m/s^2} = 9.1 {\rm gee}$$

Now as far as the centrifugal acceleration you noted 270 degress in 5/6 of a second, which means

$$ \omega = \frac{270°}{0.833 {\rm sec}} = 5.65 {\rm rad/s} $$

We have to estimate the distance of the person from the center of rotation. To me it looks like the center of rotation is in the middle of the dash of the car. The driver got flung to the window which is like 2ft away ($r=0.61{\rm m}$). The acceleration due to the rotation is

$$ a = r \omega^2 = 19.5 {\rm m/s^2} = 2.0 {\rm gee}$$

So there you have it, 9 gee of acceleration due to stopping and 2 gee due to rotation.

Comment: I would have thought more, but I was estimating the center of rotation at the bumper, not the dash. You are correct about the axis being more to the center of the vehicle. Thank you for working through it! The little bit of research I've done indicates 50-95G is the estimated force needed to cause concussion...so hopefully he just had a headache, not something worse.

Comment: It depends if he was restrained or not, and if his head hit something hard.

Comment: He was restrained. Was having difficulty getting himself out of the belt when I got his door forced open to check on him. I can't say for sure, but I'd imagine he hit the B post or the driver's window, though the window was not starred from an impact.

Comment: I hope everyone walked away with no long term injuries.